# Git, heroku, pre-receive hook declined

Tags: python, git, heroku

So I was trying to host a simple python script on Heroku.com, but encountered this error. After a little googling, I found this on the Heroku's website: `git, Heroku: pre-receive hook declined, Make sure you are pushing a repo that contains a proper supported app ( Rails, Django etc.) and you are not just pushing some random repo to test it out.`

Problem is I have no idea how these work, and few tutorials I looked up were for more detailed use of those frameworks. What I need to know is how can i use them with a simple 1 file python script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the preceding build log output. That message is just the final one, and doesn't contain any useful information.

Comment: You probably need to add a requirements.txt file to your present working directory. Can you show us all files that you pushed to Heroku? Are you sending a Flask/Django server?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it. It was about some unused modules in requirements.txt, I'm an idiot for not reading the output properly ‍♂️